# PHP Issue with PHAR and ZLIB

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, zlib, phar

I'm trying to install `phpbrew` on my system.

Ubuntu Server Raring Ringtail 13.04 x64

I downloaded the file from [GitHub](https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew)

It has all permissions set, but everytime i try to decompress and install the phar file it throws me this error:

```
kkoci@ubuntuweb:~/phpbrew$ php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini phpbrew 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'zlib extension is     required for gz compressed .phar file "/home/kkoci/phpbrew/phpbrew"' in     /home/kkoci/phpbrew/phpbrew:3
Stack trace:
#0 /home/kkoci/phpbrew/phpbrew(3): Phar::mapPhar('phpbrew.phar')
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/kkoci/phpbrew/phpbrew on line 3
```

zlib extension is already enabled, on web version (apache) of php and on cli as well.

These are the interesting lines of the `phpbrew` phar

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
Phar::mapPhar('phpbrew.phar');require  'phar://phpbrew.phar/Universal/ClassLoader/SplClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Universal\ClassLoader\SplClassLoader;
$classLoader->addFallback( 'phar://phpbrew.phar' );
$classLoader->register();require 'phar://phpbrew.phar/scripts/phpbrew-  emb.php';__HALT_COMPILER(); ?>
```

Please, i can't figure out how to bypass this, as i wrote before, everything is enabled, zlib and phar, i don't know, maybe i'm missing some phar configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, fixed it doing a configure --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/ext/zlib
and then a make install